# Using a for-loop and PrintWriter, how do I create multiple randomly named files each that have a set of their own code in them?

Tags: java

Basically the issue is after compiling running and entering an input. Only one file is being created. Everything is working properly except for when I enter a number larger than one. Entering a number greater than one should allow me to have multiple files each with random names being generated right from what I understand, right? Instead it chooses to only create one file with a random name and does everything normally, except for create those few extra files I told it to.

This is for personal entertainment and I am using notepad++ to create this then I am compiling and running it using javac and java in the command prompt. I am basically using what we learned in class a couple days ago to create this plus a lot of extra things that I had to do research on but I really want to find out how to do this and couldn't find much on doing it in a for-loop which is how I want to do it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class rangen {

    static String getnumlet(int n) {

        String numlet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqr" +
            "stuvwxyz0123456789";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
            int index = (int)(numlet.length() * Math.random());

            sb.append(numlet.charAt(index));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int length = 10;
        int amount = 0;

        String printername = (rangen.getnumlet(length) + ".java");
        String name = (printername.substring(0 ,
            printername.indexOf('.')).trim());
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter tofile = null;

        System.out.print("Enter the amount of files you want to create: ");
        amount = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= amount ; i++) {

            try {

                tofile = new PrintWriter(printername);

                tofile.print("// Creator: Unknown...\n");
                tofile.print("// Date Created: 9-28-2019\n");
                tofile.print("// Last Modified: 9-28-2019\n");
                tofile.print("// Description: This file was \n" + 
                    "//     randomly generated.\n");
                tofile.print("public class " + name + " {\n");
                tofile.print("  public static void main(String[] args) {\n");
                tofile.print("      private static final double inf = \n" +
                    "           Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;\n");
                tofile.print("      for (int i = 1 ; i <= inf ; i++) {\n");
                tofile.print("          System.out.print(\"yeet \" + i);\n");
                tofile.print("      }\n");
                tofile.print("  }\n");
                tofile.print("}\n");
                for (int x = 0 ; x <= 5; x++ ) {

                    tofile.print("// LOL " + x + "\n");
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("couldn't create " + printername);
            }
            tofile.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say you put in the value of 3 in the console. Then I expect it to create three separate files each having the code in it that I told it to write to the file. No error messages should occur but only one file is being made for me instead of 3.

Comment: just a suggestion... but try using more meaningful variable names. You called something printername but it was actually a file name, that kind of thing makes it more difficult to understand your code.

Comment: That actually cleared up quite a bit of confusion in some of my other programs as well, I changed the variables to more accurate names and it is by far easier to see what's going on. _Thank you for that._

Comment: Don't edit the question so that it no longer exhibits the problem solved in the answer. Reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate a new random file name each iteration of the `for` loop. As written your program generates a single random file name and uses the same name each iteration.

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= amount ; i++) {
    String printername = (rangen.getnumlet(length) + ".java");
    String name = printername.substring(0, printername.indexOf('.')).trim();

    try {
        tofile = new PrintWriter(printername);
        ...
    }
}
```